# Python: How to access data from this type of list?

Tags: python, list, nested

Quick Python question: How do I access data from a nested list like this:

```
{'album': [u'Rumours'], 'comment': [u'Track 3'], 'artist': [u'Fleetwood Mac'], 'title': [u'Never Going Back Again'], 'date': [u'1977'], 'genre': [u'Rock'], 'tracknumber': [u'03']}
```

I tried `listname[0][0]` but it returns the error:
 `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'lower'`

So how would I go about doing this?

Comment: Your example is a dict, not a list.  Have you tried accessing it with for example `foo['genre'][0]`?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a list. This is a dictionary.

The dictionary is not ordered, and thus it cannot be accessed through a numeric index*.

You must refer to to it like this: `listname['album']`

The above will return you a list with one element (which happens to be a list): `[u'Rumours']`, to acces a list, you do as usual.

So altogether:

```
listname['album'][0] 
# Will output the string inside the list.
```

Notice that the list could have more elements, so you would refer them like so `[0]`,`[1]` etc.

Take a look at the [docs](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) for more information.

---

*You can do:

```
d = {2:"a",1:"b"}
print d[1] ### prints string b
```

What I meant is that you don't use zero based indexes, you use keys that can be "whatever you want" and this keys refer to values.

Comment: @user738534: Ok, no problem, I've updated my answer with a little more information just in case.

Answer (score 9):

This is not a list, it is a dictionary. It takes an immutable type as key and any type as value for every `key,value` pair. In your case this is a dictionary with `str` type keys and `list`'s as values. You must first extract the list from the dictionary, and then the first element from the list, assuming you meant that:

```
somedict = {"test": [u"spam"], "foo": [u"bar"]}
print(somedict["test"][0])
```

Please note that a dictionary is not type-bound and can mix types:

```
somedict = {1: "test", "foo": ["bar", "spam"]}
```

And some more information about dictionaries can be found here: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Comment: @wkoomson: Then please consider accepting my answer :) You can do that by clicking the check button on the left of my answer.

Comment: @wkoomson:  As already asked nicely by @nightcracker, this answer should be accepted if it worked the best.